# evaluation order of function itself and its arguments

Tags: operator-precedence

The wiki page on [Evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) talks about different strategies on evaluating function arguments, but I wonder what the order between the function itself and its arguments is.

Using CoffeeScript as an example:

```
p = console.log

(do -> p 1; p) (do -> p 2; 4), (do -> p 3; 5)
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4 5
```

According to the output, we know that function itself is evaluated firstly, then all arguments left-to-right.

It doesn't seem too insane to evaluate the function after all arguments as well so that the output would become:

```
2
3
1
4 5
```

Any languages do this? If not, why not? Where can I find more info on this? (What's the keyword I should use for searching?)

Comment: The second method you suggest is actually quite useful if you tend to want choice in whether the invoked expression is evaluated first or not, because you can explicitly do so the line before in a single line. Whereas, in your first method if you wanted to explicitly invoke the arguments first, you would have to have a 'line' per argument (unless using other sugary stuff).

Comment: Scrap that, coffeescript gives you the sugar: `a = [(do -> p 2; 4), (do -> p 3; 5)]`
`(do -> p 1; p) a...`